# SQL Server, create stored procedure to insert rows within date range for each record with the days of no transaction

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server I am trying to create a stored procedure.

For each row with no daily transaction, How to insert rows (with 'idle' entries) from the last date of entry to now.

```
id  |   date         |   workdone       |
----+----------------+------------------+
1   |   2019-07-31   |   clean engine   |
2   |   2019-08-01   |   change filter  |
3   |   2019-08-02   |   idle           |
4   |   2019-08-03   |   idle           |
5   |   2019-08-04   |   idle           |
6   |   2019-08-05   |   idle           |
7   |   2019-08-06   |   idle           |
```

Comment: [Create Procedure Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: you wanted to insert those lines with `idle` workdone ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to insert those lines with `idle` ?

One way is to use recursive cte

```
-- create sample table
declare @sample table
(
    [id]        int identity,
    [date]      date,
    [workdone]  varchar(20)
)

-- create some sample data
insert into @sample ([date], [workdone])
values  ('2019-07-31', 'clean engine'),
    ('2019-08-01', 'change filter')

-- the recursive query
; with rcte as
(
    -- this is the anchor item
    select  [date] = dateadd(day, 1, max([date])) from @sample

    union all

    -- this is the recursive item
    select  [date] = dateadd(day, 1, [date])
    from    rcte
    where   [date]  < convert(date, getdate())
)
--  insert it into sample table
insert into @sample ([date], [workdone])
select  [date], 'idle' as workdone 
from    rcte

-- show the final result
select  *
from    @sample
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `procedure` I suggest a function with return type as table would be better for your case.
Since the result of function is directly used in any subquery for further use.

For your example you may try this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETDATERANGE ( @DATE DATE )  --- here date is from which date to today's date you want your date range.
RETURNS @TABLE TABLE ( ID INT, DATERANGE DATE, WORKDONE VARCHAR(MAX) )
AS
BEGIN


; WITH YOURTABLE AS (    ---- here this is your table, feel free to change this as per your need
    SELECT 1 AS ID, '2019-08-04' AS DATE, 'CLEAN ENGINE' AS WORKDONE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID, '2019-08-01' AS DATE, 'MY DATE' AS WORKDONE
),
n AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @DATE, getdate()) + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.all_objects
)
,CT AS (
SELECT n, DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @DATE) AS DATERANGE FROM n
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE ( ID, DATERANGE, WORKDONE )
SELECT C.N AS ID, C.DATERANGE, CASE WHEN YTAB.DATE IS NULL THEN 'IDLE' ELSE YTAB.WORKDONE END AS WORKDONE
FROM CT AS C LEFT OUTER JOIN YOURTABLE AS YTAB ON C.DATERANGE=YTAB.DATE

RETURN

End
```

RESULT:

By calling this function, in this way...

```
 SELECT * FROM DBO.GETDATERANGE ( '2019-08-01' )
```

You'll get result

```
ID  DATERANGE   WORKDONE
1   2019-08-01  MY DATE       --- this is record from your table 
2   2019-08-02  IDLE
3   2019-08-03  IDLE
4   2019-08-04  CLEAN ENGINE    --- this is record from your table 
5   2019-08-05  IDLE
6   2019-08-06  IDLE
```

Or if you want to use this as procedure you may convert it for same as per your need.